# Status bar takes background of Main.storyboard splash-screen

Tags: ios, storyboard, pwabuilder

I am transforming a PWA into a iOS application using PWABuilder.com and Xcode/Swift.
The problem I am encountering is that PWABuilder is ignoring my theme_color. I want the splash-screen background to be orange and the status bar to be white, or even better, the background-color defined in my CSS. When using my PWA purely standalone, this works. The colors get only messed up in the iOS/PWABuilder version.

Now I am trying to edit the colors in Xcode. I see two storyboards. I guess `LaunchSreen.storyboard` is the splash screen. This background-color is set to orange and is perfectly fine.

There also is `Main.storyboard`. I guess this is launched after the LaunchScreen. Because it is a PWA, I guess PWABuilder only inserted a kind of WebView into the Main-storyboard. The problem with the Main-storyboard/WebView is that it has a splash-screen of its own.

**Main.storyboard:**

[image: Main.storyboard]

Currently, I have just hidden this splash screen and gave this whole view a white background-color and hidden the splash screen of the Main-storyboard. This gives the wanted behavior: An orange splash screen and a white status bar. But when loading the Main storyboard a white screen is shown for a few seconds (because I hid its splash-screen).

I thought I could make the background-color of the splash-screen in the Main orange (so it matches the splash-screen of LaunchSreen.storyboard) and the WebView's background white (so the status bar is white). This does not work. The status bars takes the color of the background-color of the splash-screen in Main.storyboard.

How do I fix this?